# Use Abel's Theorem to approximate the Wronskian

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Use Abel's Theorem to approximate the Wronskian: $$y"-y'-12y=0; y_1=e^{-3x}, y_2=e^{4x}$$
I don't understand how to apply Abel's Theorem by referencing my textbooks explanation $W(y_1, y_2)(x)=(c)\text{exp}\left[-\int{p(x)dx}\right]$.
If someone could help me out that would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

If $y_1$ and $y_2$ are solutions to the DEQ, $y'' + p(x) y' + q(x) y = 0$, then the Wronskian is given by:

$$W = ce^{-\int p(x)~dx}$$

For your DEQ, we have:

$$p(x) = -1$$

**Spoiler**

> $W(y_1,y_2) = ce^x$ (Note: this gives us the Wronskian up to a multiplicative constant (the actual Wronskian is $W(y_1,y_2) = 7e^x)$.

Comment: Haha! Thank you, I don't know why I wasn't able to process that :P

Comment: You are very welcome, but note the comment that using this approach, $c = W(y_1(x_0),y_2(x_0))$, but that requires knowing the Wronskian ahead of time, so $c=7$ in reality, but showing that it is a constant is not bad as we know it is linearly independent. Regards

Comment: Nice use of the spoiler! +1

Comment: Thanks! Yes, crossing my fingers (see the Dr. this morning to <hopefully> confirm today is my last!)